Help deriving convolution with a slanted Dirac delta line
I need help with a derivation. Here is the equation I'm working with:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
      r(x) & =\int f(ax + by, y) \, dy \\
           & = \int \int f(\tau, y) \delta(\tau-(ax + by)) \, d\tau \, dy \\
           & =(f * \delta(ax + by))(x, y) \\
           & =f(x,y) * \delta(ax + by)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I want to show that tilting ( f ) and integrating in the ( y )-direction is equivalent to convolving ( f ) with a slanted Dirac delta line in the ( x )-direction.
Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

The equation doesn’t make sense. The LHS is a function of $x$ but the RHS is written as a function of $x$ and $y$.

What are the definitions of Dirac delta and convolution you are using?

I understand that the LHS of the first equation is a function of $x$ only because of the integration over $y$.
On the RHS, f is initially a function of both x and y, and I would like to show equivalence after convolution with δ(ax+by).
The main goal is to demonstrate that tilting f (via the argument ax+by) and integrating in the y-direction is equivalent to convolving f with a slanted Dirac delta line in the x-direction.
Any clarification or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Dirac Delta line is as in the image a line that is zero expect an the argument, for example δ(x,y) is as point in the center and  δ(x) is as vertical line. and  δ(x+u) is a slanted line.

I don't think your notation is consistent with the definition of convolution.

The definition of convolution is $$[g(\tau) * h(\tau)](t)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g(\tau)\, h(t-\tau) \, d\tau\tag{1}$$ so for $$g(\tau)=f(\tau,y)\tag{2},$$ $$h(\tau)=\delta(\tau)\tag{3},$$ and $$t=a x+b y\tag{4}$$ one has $$[f(\tau,y) * \delta(\tau)](a x+b y)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau,y)\, \delta(a x + by-\tau) \, d\tau\\=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau,y)\, \delta(\tau-(a x + by)) \, d\tau=f(a x+b y,y)\tag{5}$$ since $\delta(z)$ is an even function of $z$.

So introducing the nested convolution integral just leads back to $$r(x)=\int\limits f(a x+b y,y) \, dy\tag{6}.$$

but how to get to the last step in my eq: $f(x,y) * \delta(...)$?

@tag I don't understand your question. Do you not understand formula (5) in my answer above? The convolution notation in the last two steps of your answer above is inconsistent with formula (5) in my answer above and incorrect.

@tag My answer above illustrates $$r(x)=\int [f(\tau,y) * \delta(\tau)](a x+b y) , dy=\int f(a x+b y,y) , dy$$ so I don't understand why you think you can evaluate the outer integral as a convolution.
